# Is it safe to skip account_process_tick for a given task?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a Linux `Loadable Kernel Module` where I hook `account_process_tick` Kernel function.

This function checks if `tsk` has a `PF_INVISIBLE` flag and if it does then it returns `void` to skip the account process tick. If `tsk` doesn't have a `PF_INVISIBLE` flag then we return the original `account_process_tick` Kernel function.

```c
/* This is our hook function for account_process_tick */
static asmlinkage void hook_account_process_tick(struct task_struct *tsk, int user)
{
    if (tsk->flags & PF_INVISIBLE) {
        return;
    }

    return orig_account_process_tick(tsk, user);
}
```

The goal of this code is to supress from commands like `top` the global CPU usage for given `tsk`.

Everything works as expected. Now I would love to know if there's any caveat doing this. Would this make my system more unstable or even crash it? If we look at the Linux Kernel source code we can see that my code is skipping [vtime_flush](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/26c19d0a8610fb233b31730fe26a31145f2d9796/include/linux/kernel_stat.h#L109) function for these `tsk`. How safe is this? Is important what `vtime_flush` does or it just computes the accounting time and then flushes it?

Comment: How are you hooking the function? `account_process_tick()` returns `void` so it seems strange that you are calling it and returning its return value from a function which returns `long`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli [Check out this source code](https://github.com/xcellerator/linux_kernel_hacking/tree/master/3_RootkitTechniques/3.6_hiding_ports), it's similar to what I'm doing but it hooks `tcp4_seq_show` Linux kernel function to hide network traffic.

Comment: I see, you should probably do `static asmlinkage void` then. Reading the return value of a `void` function like `orig_account_process_tick()` is undefined behavior in C. In any case, this was just a nitpick, doesn't have much to do with the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli You're totally right it should return `void` instead of `long`. Thanks for the heads up, I fixed it. Anyways it's still working as expected :) Now I need to figure out if it's safe to deploy it on prod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been running the code mentioned in OP for some time and I didn't experience any issue so far. So I believe it's safe to use.